# How to edit a Sharepoint list from an AngularJS list?

Tags: list-item, angularjs, edit

I am pretty new with AngularJS, and I need to be able to edit some entries of a Sharepoint list but from an AngularJS list that I made.
This is my code right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="angular.js"></script>

   <style>
        .myTable th {
            padding: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .myTable, .myTable tr, .myTable td {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 6px;
        }
        .material-icons {
            font-size: 17px;
        }
   </style>
   <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);  
        myApp.controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.editablerow = '';

            //Here I call the Sharepoint List
            $http({
                method:'GET',
                url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Contacts List')/items?$select=*,Name/Title&$expand=Name",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                var dataResults = data.d.results;
                $scope.contacts = dataResults;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Error! The list's data cannot be found.");
            });

            //And this is for the edit options
            $scope.editContent = function(contact) {
                $scope.editablerow = angular.copy(contact);
            }
            $scope.loadTemplate = function(contact) {
                if(contact.ID === $scope.editablerow.ID) return 'edit';
                else return 'view';
            }
            $scope.saveData = function(indx) {
                $scope.rows[indx] = angular.copy($scope.editablerow);
                $scope.reset();
            };
            $scope.reset = function() {
                $scope.editablerow = [];
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController" class="myCode">
            <table class="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <!--So these are the columns of my list-->
                        <th>
                            <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
                        </th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!--Here I call the results which are in the following scripts-->
                    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts" ng-include="loadTemplate(contact)">
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <!--This is the Script to show the results normally-->
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="view">
                <td>
                    <i ng-if="contact.Attachments" class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
                </td>
                <td>
                    //This is the button to open the "Edition mode"
                    <a ng-click="editContent(contact)" style="cursor:pointer">
                        <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>{{contact.ID | number}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Name.Title}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.LinkTitle}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Message}}</td>
            </script>

            <!--This is the Script to show the results in the Edit mode-->
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <i ng-if="contact.Attachments" class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="saveData($index)">Save</button>
                    <button ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
                </td>
                <td>{{contact.ID | number}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Name.Title}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="editablerow.LinkTitle" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="editablerow.Message" /></td>
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So the thing with my code is that when you click on the Edit button of each row it will open the Edition mode, there it will only be able to edit the **LinkTitle** and the **Message** fields.
Obiously the code doesn't work, when you click **Save** it doesn't upload the changes to the list.
I know I'm missing something and I'd like to know what is it ..and I would appreciate if someone can work an answer using my example code :D Thanks

---

**CODE UPDATE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="angular.js"></script>

   <style>
        .myTable th {
            padding: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .myTable, .myTable tr, .myTable td {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 6px;
        }
        .material-icons {
            font-size: 17px;
        }
   </style>
   <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);  
        myApp.controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.editablerow = '';

            //Here I call the Sharepoint List
            $http({
                method:'GET',
                url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Contacts List')/items?$select=*,Name/Title&$expand=Name",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                var dataResults = data.d.results;
                $scope.contacts = dataResults;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Error! The list's data cannot be found.");
            });

            //And this is for the edit options
            $scope.editContent = function(contact) {
                $scope.editablerow = angular.copy(contact);
            }
            $scope.loadTemplate = function(contact) {
                if(contact.ID === $scope.editablerow.ID) return 'edit';
                else return 'view';
            }

            //Here's the part that was missing, but still doesn't work :/
            $scope.saveData = function(indx) {
                $scope.rows[indx] = angular.copy($scope.editablerow);
                var data = {
                    __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.Contacts_x0020_ListListItem" },
                    Title: "Some Title"
                };
                $http({
                    method:'POST',
                    url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Contacts List')/getItemById("+indx+")",
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
                        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH", //Not sure if maybe it is "MERGE"?
                        "If-Match": "*"
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify(data)
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("Updated");
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("Error! The data cannot be updated.");
                });
                $scope.reset();
            };
            $scope.reset = function() {
                $scope.editablerow = [];
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController" class="myCode">
            <table class="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <!--So these are the columns of my list-->
                        <th>
                            <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
                        </th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!--Here I call the results which are in the following scripts-->
                    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts" ng-include="loadTemplate(contact)">
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <!--This is the Script to show the results normally-->
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="view">
                <td>
                    <i ng-if="contact.Attachments" class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
                </td>
                <td>
                    //This is the button to open the "Edition mode"
                    <a ng-click="editContent(contact)" style="cursor:pointer">
                        <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>{{contact.ID | number}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Name.Title}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.LinkTitle}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Message}}</td>
            </script>

            <!--This is the Script to show the results in the Edit mode-->
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <i ng-if="contact.Attachments" class="material-icons">attach_file</i>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="saveData($index)">Save</button>
                    <button ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
                </td>
                <td>{{contact.ID | number}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.Name.Title}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="editablerow.LinkTitle" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="editablerow.Message" /></td>
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes @Sunil is right. You are missing code for updating your list..

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the update/post request on save click, in your script there is no **post request** is mention so how SharePoint will know what to update if you are not having a post request same like you are having a **get request** for the Contact list.

Please add a post request in below line

```
    $scope.saveData = function(indx) {
     alert(indx);
     $scope.rows[indx] = angular.copy($scope.editablerow);
     var data = {
        __metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.Contacts_x0020_ListListItem" },
        Title: "Some title"};

       $http({
                method:'POST',
                url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Contacts List')/getItemById("+indx+")",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                 "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                 "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                 "X-Http-Method": "PATCH",
                    "If-Match": "*"
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("updated");
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Error! The  data cannot be updated.");
             });
                $scope.reset();
            };
```

[Refer this link](https://www.rightpoint.com/thought/2014/10/23/updating-sharepoint-list-items-with-sharepoint-s-rest-api-in-javascript)

Comment: Okay I added the code as the one you are telling me, but still the code runs the same: when I try to edit something and click "Save", it just recharges the page and no update is made. Is there something else I'm missing?
Also from where are you taking the name "SP.Data.ContactsListListItem" in the"__metadata" part?

Comment: are you getting error alert ,

And to get SP.Data.ContactsListListItem
you have to make a get request or you can check the below hitting endpoint on browser.
"your site url/" _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Contacts List')/listItemEntityTypeFullName

Comment: No, I'm not getting any alerts... It just realoads the page with no change in the list.
Second doubt: the "Title" part after the "__metadata", what is that?

Comment: its column name in the list , and please refer the link  i mention in the answer, queries related updating in the list.

Comment: I referred to the link but sincerely I don't understand a lot of this.. :(
I updated my Code as you can see above, there's how I added the part that you told me. But I'm still kinda blocked because I don't really know a lot about REST APIs and still learning about Angular

Comment: hi i am afraid that "__metadata: { "type": "SP.Data.ContactsListListItem" }" might me wrong , can you help with your list url like "your site url/Lists/ContactsList/AllItems.aspx"

Comment: Yeah I realize that, I already edited the code above (I did checked the name of this part as you said in the browser and shows that "space" as x0020). And my list is from a corporate's site, so.. here it is: https://**SiteURL**/Lists/Contacts%20List/AllItems.aspx
I don't know if maybe there's something wrong with the **Save button** which calls ng-click="saveData($index)" and I really don't know what $index does :s ..I know, I'm trying to do stuff that I don't understand at all, that's why I said I'm pretty new with this UnU

Comment: hi updated the code SP.Data.Contacts_x0020_ListListItem as list name is "Contacts%20List" and $index is the item id for the list item  that you need to perform update operation. For trail you use a hard cord value and try updating the list.

Comment: Okay, so I added the alert and it tells me the number of each row, but I still don't know what the problem is. The list is still not saving the changes in the Sharepoint list. The console returns this error: "Cannot set property '1' of undefined at Scope.$scope.saveData" (where '1' is the value of "indx").

Comment: index is item id of list item which you are binding as row id for the row, please check with SharePoint list item ID in list and try again